# Setting up Silex project - where?

Tags: silex

This is a very basic question about using Silex for the first time.

I want to install [this project](https://github.com/khepin/tsusbos) which was linked from [this tutorial](http://sf.khepin.com/2011/04/a-first-silex-project/). I have already installed Silex via Composer per [these instructions](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/download).

What I need to know is, should I put the project inside the Silex folder I created when I installed it with Composer? Do I need a new instance of Silex for each project I use it for, or do I use one for all the projects, and keep those in other folders?

I'm used to Drupal, if that helps with answering this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different silex projects might require different package dependencies. You should have 1 composer.json per project , with it's own vendor folder.

What you should do :

fork this repo on github:

> https://github.com/fabpot/silex-skeleton

create you own base project , and just create projects automatically with composer ( you can publish your default project on packagist.org then use composer to install it):

To use the default skeleton used by Fabien Potencier , use this command :

```
composer create-project fabpot/silex-skeleton -sdev
```

it will be easier to deploy your application on the server once you are done developing it if you use separate silex installations.

Comment: What do you suggest if one uses Windows?

Comment: it is the exact same method on windows , if git is installed.